# Ingress for Kubernetes Wordpress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I've recently setup a Kubernetes cluster and I am brand new to all of this so it's quite a bit to take in. Currently I am trying to setup and Ingress for wordpress deployments. I am able to access through nodeport but I know nodeport is not recommended so I am trying to setup the ingress. I am not exactly sure how to do it and I can't find many guides. I followed this to setup the NGINX LB https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example    and I used this to setup the WP Deployment https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/admin/configure/use-nfs-volumes/#inspect-the-deployment

I would like to be able to have multiple WP deployments and have an Ingress that resolves to the correct one, but I really can't find much information on it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your ingress to forward traffic to a different service depending on path.

An example of such a confugration is this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: s1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /bar
        backend:
          serviceName: s2
          servicePort: 80
```

Read the kubernetes [documentation on ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) for more info.

PS: In order for this to work you need an ingress controller like the one in the links in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on AWS, I highly recommend [ALB ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller) in conjunction with [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns). These in combination with Wordpress Multisite give you some powerful options when it comes to providing dynamic ingress to new sites.

If you start running into any wonky issues (e.g. unable to login to the admin, redirect loops, disappearing media) after getting that all set up, I wrote a [guide](https://labs.meanpug.com/mistakes-running-wordpress-on-kubernetes/) on some of the more common issues people run into when running Wordpress on Kubernetes, might be worth having a look!